# Maximum surface area of a cylinder inside a sphere solution and question about the solution

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I am trying to understand a statement in the solution to the maximum surface questions. I have inserted the image below
[Solution to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riRGU.jpg)

I have underlined the portion of the solution that I cannot comprehend. Can anybody explain to me in a different way? Why do we reject the root with (+) sign?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

"... since it doesn't satisfy $(\star)$."

The layout of the solution is a little cluttered, so it's not as easy to find the $(\star)$ as it ideally would be, but it occurs just two lines above the part you underlined:
$$
x \sqrt{r^2 - x^2} = r^2 - 2x^2  \qquad(\star)
$$

The area calculation has been set up so that $x$ is positive
(the height of the cylinder must be positive, and is set at $2x$).
The symbol $\sqrt\quad$ always denotes the positive square root (or zero).
So the left-hand side of $(\star)$ is positive or zero.
But then the right-hand side must also be positive or zero, so
$$
r^2 - 2x^2 \geq 0.
$$
It follows that 
$x^2 \leq \frac12 r^2 = \frac{5}{10} r^2 < \frac{5+\sqrt5}{10} r^2.$
In other words, $\frac{5+\sqrt5}{10} r^2$ is just too big to be $x^2$;
if we try to set $x^2 = \frac{5+\sqrt5}{10} r^2,$ 
we'll violate the equation labeled with $(\star).$

Comment: @Adaptron Yes, I did.